# Sharepoint 2013 - Search crawl errors

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, search, crawling, search-scope

I have a search crawl errors - I have more errors than successes. The files I am looking for are from document libraries and the main error is **The first attempt to crawl this object failed. Another attempt is being made**
I have looked over the logs and I really do not know what I am looking for in the list. Would someone provide me with a starting point?

Comment: Please post the errors from the crawl logs.

Comment: The first attempt to crawl this object failed. Another attempt is being made. ( Failed to retieve blob from URI
Last crawl- 10:31:51
Last 24 hours - 10:31:51
Last 7 days - 09:53:20
Last 30 days - 03:38:48
Successes - 7,484
Warnings - 62
Errors - 9,792
Top Level Errors - 0
Deletes - 7,452

Comment: You may have to go deeper in the crawl logs or look at the ULS logs. I assume you have checked the URLs and ensured that the Crawl Account has access to the content and that there are no certificate or DNS errors.

Comment: Yep - account access is fine - when it comes to the ULS logs - I am not sure what I am looking for...the logs are there but long and extensive

Comment: Be sure you are getting all the way to the details in the crawl logs. There are eror groups then click into the error group for an error for each item error. In ULS you are looking for the SharePoint Search and Crawl errors, probably High, Critical and Unexpected.

Comment: The ULS Viewer from Microsoft might be helpful when going through the ULS logs:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44020

Comment: Thanks for the ULS logs download. Seems to be a lot of data to trawl. I have come across this error - System.IO.IOException: The specified network name is no longer available. I really do not know what is significant and what is not.

Comment: I have also come across these two errors - No windows identity for mysite\sp_content & SPSecurityContext: Could not retrieve a valid windows identity for username 'mysite\sp_content' with UPN 'sp_content@mysite.com. 'UPN is required when Kerberos constrained delegation is used. Exception: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): Access is denied

Comment: After much searching through files and logs we decided to reconfigure the alternate mapping and reset the search application, restart the search service and run a full crawl. Finally - fixed